# When inserting a node to root and calling fireTreeNodesInserted, what TreeModelEvent parameters to use?

Tags: java, swing, tree, treeview, awt

I've read the [fireTreeNodesInserted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#fireTreeNodesInserted(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D) doco but "path - the path to the parent the nodes were added to" is confusing me.

**General Question:** Where would I find good example code for implementing the MutableTreeNode notifications to TreeModelListener ?

**Specific Question:** In this case the root node is having the nodes added. So what to use as the path?  The root has no parent.

I thought a path should always include the node being referred to. Am I wrong?

In this case what path should the getPathFromRoot() be?

```
    public void insert(MutableTreeNode child, int index) {
        logger.debug("this='" + this + "', child='" + child + "' at index="
                + index);

        // If child has existing parent then super will remove it.
        // TODO Fire event on old parent for losing a node.
        super.insert(child, index);

        // Inform our listeners that we have inserted node(s).
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#fireTreeNodesInserted(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object[],%20int[],%20java.lang.Object[])
        TreeModelEvent e = new TreeModelEvent(this, 

                getPathFromRoot(),   //  <======== HERE

                new int[] { index }, new TreeNode[] { child });
        logger.debug("this=" + this + " fire event " + e);
        fireTreeNodesInserted(e);
    }
```

```
    public void testAddFireTreeNodesInserted() {
        NodeJTreeModel model = new NodeJTreeModel();
        Node root = new Node();
        TestTreeModelListener listener = new TestTreeModelListener();
        model.addTreeModelListener(listener);
        model.setRoot(root);
        Node child1 = new Node();
        root.insert(child1, 0);
        var got = listener.getNodesInserted();

        // These expected values might not be correct. 
        assertEquals(1, got.size());
        assertEquals(root, got.get(0).getSource());
        assertEquals(1, got.get(0).getPath().length);
        assertEquals(root, got.get(0).getPath()[0]);
        assertEquals(new int[] { 0 }, got.get(0).getChildIndices());
        assertEquals(1, got.get(0).getChildren().length);
        assertEquals(root , got.get(0).getChildren()[0]);
    }
```